# protobuf iOS5 ARC

Tags: ios5, automatic-ref-counting, protocol-buffers

I am using google protobuf in my iOS project and as it turns out, the files generated by protoc does not adhere to ARC. It does retain, dealloc and such. I am using the protobuf-objc from [here](https://github.com/booyah/protobuf-objc). Please let me know if anyone else has gone through the same issues and resolved.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quickest solution for you is probably to disable ARC for just the generated files.  Check out this question:

[How can I disable ARC for a single file in a project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6646052/how-can-i-disable-arc-for-a-single-file-in-a-project)